# Jest cannot find module 'config'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm using Jest to test my api calls file, when I run a simple test I've got an error **Cannot find module 'config'** from 'api.service.js' which is an import at the top of my api.service.js file:

```
//api.service.js    
import config from "config"; //get data from my webpack.config.js
export const apiService = {getmyData};
function getmyData() {
  let queryString = `${config.API}/api/datacall`;

  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      client.get(`${config.API}/api/datacall`).then(result => {
        return resolve(result );
      });
    },
    error => {
      return reject(error);
    }
  );
}
```

Test File in the same folder as the above

```
//api.spec.js
import getmyDatafrom "./api.service";

const domain = "http://fakeapi.com";

const mockedConsolelog = jest.spyOn(global.console, "log");
const mockedConsoleerror = jest.spyOn(global.console, "error");
```

Why can't my test file get to my config like the api.service.js?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to do the import with a relative path.

```
import config from "./config";
```

Otherwise, it tries to import something from an npm module called config.

Comment: The import works in the api.service.js but I got an error I soon as I try to test function inside the file